# Dig out some remaining rotted post or just pour in cement

Tags: concrete, fence, patio, post

Will concrete harden although some rotted wood is still in hole?

Comment: Yes concrete will still harden...what you are trying to accomplish, and in what context would make this question more answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Highly recommend you dig out the rotted post, especially for a patio. Do it right the first time, going back later will be a nightmare.

If you want to take the lazy way out, cut the post and bury it. Add another one directly next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Hydration is the chemical process by which concrete mixtures harden. Absent a retarding admixture, the hydration reaction occurs in any proper concrete mix. Wood, rotten or otherwise, is not typically a retarding admixture.

Embedding rotten wood in a foundation is not consistent with good practice, industry standards, and building codes. Furthermore, embedding wood in concrete is, in general, a sub-optimal practice.